# Model biased towards low frequency data?

Tags: training, bias

Generally model gets biased towards data_samples/target whose frequency is high in training data set.
Is it possible during training that model gets biased towards low frequency training data set.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question and problem?

Comment: We have a dataset of binary classifier. Where class 1 data is huge whereas class 0 is having very less data, i.e. data is skewed. During model training, its quite possible that model should be biased towards class 1 and its expected. I want to know is it also possible if model get biased toward class 0?

Answer (score 2):

With structured data, you have in general 4 challenges:

(1) Missing data

(2) Outliers

(3) Cardinality

(4) Rare values (as a rule of thumb <5%)

Rare values in categorical variables tend to cause over-fitting, particularly in tree based methods. Ph.D. Data Scientist Soledad Galli has an amazing course on the subject (Udemy: "Feature Engineering". Below a screenshot from her course, but to be fair to her, I'm not going to post the solution.

[image]